# ¿Cómo puedo crear 2 o más obetos para que ejecuten un programa en paralelo?

Tags: c#

soy nuevo en c# y estoy realizando un programa que me genera objetos en una clase Main a partir de otra clase pero me los crea uno detrás de otro y me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de que me los genere a la vez.
Mi código realiza conexiones SSH para descargar datos de varias máquinas y me gustaría que estas descargas se realizasen en paralelo.
Un saludo!

```
     class Ejemplo
     {

          public static void Main(string[] args){
          
               Programa objeto1 = new Programa("atributo1");
               Programa objeto2 = new Programa("atributo2");

          }

    }

   class Programa
   {
       public Programa(string atributo)
       {
        //Aqui va el programa que realizan los objetos
       }
   }
```

En este caso quiero que objeto1 y objeto2 vayan el paralelo.

Comment: Busca cómo trabajar con hilos en C#, es la única forma de trabajar en paralelo.

Comment: Puedes usar la [TPL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)

Comment: La documentación de [programación paralela en C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-processing-and-concurrency) tiene toda la información que buscas acerca de procesamiento en paralelo y también tiene las respuestas a mucha posibles futuras preguntas que podrías tener. Si tienes alguna pregunta específica que la documentación no pueda responder, o no sea completamente claro, aquí estaremos para ayudarte.